# $yz\,dx-2xz\,dy+(xy-y^3z)\,dz=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology

[My attempt at the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXZrA.jpg)

[What I don't know is do we integrate partially w.r.t. z to find the value of Φ (z) here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GstYe.jpg)

> > $$
> >   \require{begingroup}
> >   \begingroup
> > \newcommand{\dd}{\;\mathrm{d}}$$
> >     $$yz\dd x-2xz \dd y + (xy-y^3z) \dd z=0.\tag{1}$$
> >     $P=yz$, $Q=-2xz$ and $R=xy-y^3z$
> >     Now
> >     \begin{align*}
> > &P\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}\right)+
> > Q\left(\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}\right)+
> > R\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}\right)\\[.8em]
> > &=P(-2x-x+3y^2z)+Q(y-y)+R(z+2z)\\
> > &=yz(-3x+3y^2z)+(-2xz)(0)+(xy-y^3z)(z+2z)\\
> > &=-3xzy+3y^3z^2+0+3xyz-3y^3z^2\\
> > &=0
> > \end{align*}
> >     Hence equation $(1)$ is integrable.
> >     Let $z$ be a constant in $(1)$, then $\dd z=0$.
> >     Integrating both sides
> >     \begin{align*}
> > \int\frac1{2xz}\dd x-\int\frac1{2yz}\dd y&=0\\
> > \frac1{2z}\ln x - \frac1z \ln y &= const\\
> > \frac{x^{1/2}}y &= \Phi(z) \tag{2}
> > \end{align*}
> >     Differentiating w.r.t $x$, $y$, $z$
> >     $$\frac{x^{-1/2}}{2y} \dd x + \left(-\frac{x^{1/2}}{y^2}\right)\dd y+(-\Phi'(z)) \dd z = 0 \tag{3}$$
> >     From equations $(1)$ and $(3)$
> >     $$\frac{yz}{1/(2x^{1/2}y)}=\frac{-2xz}{-x^{1/2}/y^2}=\frac{xy-y^3z}{-\Phi'(z)}.$$
> >     $$\endgroup$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find an integrating factor. If you treat this problem like a puzzle you can combine like terms to find
$$
y\,d(xz)-2(xz)\,dy=y^3zdz
$$
and from that that you get an integrable expression by dividing by $y^3$, that is, the integrating factor should turn out to be $y^{-3}$.

---

In your solution, I'd have avoided the square root to get
$$
xy^{-2}=\Phi(z)
$$
as the equation for the solution surface.
Then the derivative of that is
$$
y^{-2}\,dx-2xy^{-3}\,dy =\Phi'(z)\,dz\\
yz\,dx - 2xz\,dy = y^3z\Phi'(z)\,dz\\
\implies 
y^3z\Phi'(z)\,dz=(y^3z-xy)\,dz\implies \Phi'(z)=1-z^{-1}\Phi(z)
$$
which can now be easily solved.

---

In your version with $Φ(z)=\frac{x^{1/2}}y$, pick one of the relations and eliminate $y$ against $Φ$. The first two fractions are equal after simplification, the equality to the last term gives
$$
2x^{1/2}y^2z=y^3\frac{Φ(z)^2-z}{-Φ'(z)}\iff 2zΦ'(z)Φ(z)=z-Φ(z)^2\implies zΦ(z)^2=\frac12z^2+C
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)